# Detect touch event on android even when screen is off?

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to detect programatically that a touch event has occured even when phone screen is off ?

Comment: don't think so, but some ROM do it for "tap to wake up" when screen is locked. But You can't have this functionnality for an app, maybe modify kernel or something like that